# How to implement "new mail icon" for roughly 100 clients? Central server polling or local client polling?

Tags: .net, wcf, sql-server-2008, long-polling, polling

Following scenario: We have got a database table, in which new mail messages for the users are stored. When a user has our client application running, the app needs to display an icon that a new mail has arrived when an entry for this user is inserted in the database table.

Roughly 100 users will be logged in at the same time.

Two solutions as far as I see them:

1. Implement a service on a central server. That server polls the database regularly. Also, clients, when starting up, need to register with the server, so that they can be called back, when a new message for their user has arrived. Good: fewer database polls. Bad: More coding for the central element.
2. Every client polls the database on its own. The polling needs to happen about once a minute, so I have got 100 clients polling the database every minute. Bad idea? Or still ok?

So, which option would you go for?

We are using .NET 4.0 for our clients and MS SQL Server 2008 as database.

Also, in case you vote for solution 1: Would a WCF service be a good idea? Any links or ideas around my scenario would be appreciated.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for option 1. More code, but more scalability.

Answer (score 2):

Now thinking outside the box for a bit, another option you may want to explore (especially if you already have a webserver exposing content to the application), is using a library that will provide long-polling support for you. For example, [SignalR](http://signalr.net/). That way you can avoid polling from clients and just worry about receiving the notifications.

[Here's](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2011/12/06/Using-SignalR-to-broadcast-a-slide-deck.aspx) a tutorial on how to use SignalR from a console application as well as the standard web/js implementation.

Now, the other problem you have is polling the database for changes constantly. You may also be able to avoid that, by using the `SqlDependency` feature in ADO.net and SQL Server (service broker and notifications).

[Here's](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12335/Using-SqlDependency-for-data-change-events) a sample chat application using this approach of real-time notifications.

Depending on the actual amount of concurrent clients you may even be able to establish dependencies directly from clients (however this is **not** recommended).

So now, combining these two, you can have your server be aware of all your connected clients, and you can use `SqlDependency` to only trigger updates when the data in the `Messages` table really changes.
In that case you may have to get the Hub using the ConnectionManager, as shown on the [bottom section of SignalR's wiki](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs), with the title *"Broadcasting over a Hub from outside of a Hub"*.

I believe this alternative will scale better than fast polling approaches, and will considerably reduce your overall traffic between clients and the server, as well as between the server and the database.

However, beware if you are deploying in web-farms, you may have to research a bit more on SignalR's current support for it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined to go with option 1. Less clients talking to the database is a good thing and it'll be easier if you need to change the database later or add some other logic in there. A WCF service would probably work fine for this.

Comment: Any idea on how to implement such a WCF service?

Comment: Yeah. Look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.SERVICEMODEL.SERVICECONTRACTATTRIBUTE.CALLBACKCONTRACT%29;k%28CALLBACKCONTRACT%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) for some guidance on how to implement a duplex message exchange. It should allow the server to fire a callback on the client after the client has established a connection.